# Image gets downloaded every ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

Currently I'm refreshing a table with an interval and a ajax call. The ajax call returns html(to be more exact) and that html is a row that can also contain a picture if certain data from that tr is still in progress of updating.

My problem is that every ajax call, the same picture gets downloaded, is there any easy way in which it only loads once(the first call) ?

My code for the ajax:

```
function searchcar() {

        $(".carcheck").each(function () {
            if($(this).data('wait') == 1) {
                //var check = $(this).find('td:eq(0)').text();
                var item = $(this);
                var check = $(this).data('nr');
                request2 = $.ajax({
                    url: "/site/api.php",
                    type: "post",
                    data: {'getdata': 'true', 'nr': check}
                });
                request2.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    item.replaceWith(response);
                });
            }
        });
    }
    setInterval(function(){ searchcar() }, 5000);
```

My network tab looks something like this:

[image: network tab]

Answer (score 0):

```
request2.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    // Log a message to the console
                    var response = $.parseJSON(response);
                    if(response.rar !== 'wait'){
                        item.find('td:eq(1)').replaceWith(response.rar);
                    }
                    if(response.rov !== 'wait'){
                        item.find('td:eq(2)').replaceWith(response.rov);
                    }
                    if(response.aid !== 'wait'){
                        item.find('td:eq(3)').replaceWith(response.aid);
                    }
                    if(response.arr !== 'wait'){
                        item.find('td:eq(4)').replaceWith(response.arr);
                    }

                });
```

Fixed it by only replacing data thats loaded, therefore I'm not sending any `<img>` anymore through the ajax. If anyone has a better idea, I'd appreciate it, thanks!